# Calculate the value of a function for each row in a matrix without iteration through all rows

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, regression

I'm developing a genetic program and by now the whole algorithm appears to be fine. (Albeit slow...).
I'm iterating through lists of real values, one at a time and then applying a function to the list.  The format is something like :

```
trainingset=[[3.32,55,33,22],[3.322,5,3,223],[23.32,355,33,122]...]]
```

Where each inner list represents a line in the set and the last item of that list is the result of the regression in that line/individual.

The function I use is some thing like:

```
def getfitness(individual,set):
    ...
    for elem in set:
         apply the function individual to it
         fitness=fitness+(set[-1]-(result of individual with the parameters of the set))

    fitness=RMS(fitness)
    return fitness
```

So, what I'de like to know is , is there a way of calculating the function in one go, are there any libs that can do this ? I've been looking at matrices in numpy but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Jorge

Comment: What does "to no avail" mean? Numpy is designed exactly for this. You can't avoid iteration but numpy will do it in C which is much faster.

Comment: means without success.
I'm going to further explore numpy.

Comment: I guess you tried to implement your algorithm using numpy data structures and got stuck at some point? Just in case it is not clear, your best option to improve performance is almost certainly numpy.

Comment: Not yet. I'm still looking for a numpy funtion that will allow me to do it. The numpy structures i've seen still need iteration. Right now I'm doing a simple example to try the concept. I'll keep you posted . Thanks